# URL with payload like Start {{sum=(2*2.0)}} End executes in razor validation message for helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

Recently some one showed me how they could execute something on an MVC site by putting a value the website did not expect into the URL and the MVC default validation message for then ran it.

They did something like:

```
?page=Start%20%7B%7Bsum%3d(2*2.0)%7D%7D%20End
```

Which the website put in the validation message as "The value 'Start 4 END' is not valid for page." So it did the sum.

On the same site though it did not work to try to put javascript in and have it execute.

So I am a bit confused and I cannot find any information on injecting this kind of code into a site. So, is it a big problem? What other kind of code could you run using this syntax? How would you fix it so that it couldn't?

**Update - additional information:**

MVC version is 4

The page property is defined as:

```
public class SearchContext
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
}
```

This is passed to a controller so the page is remembered when the user goes back:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create( SearchContext searchOptions )
{
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel( ){
        SearchOptions = searchOptions
    };
    // .....
    return View( viewModel );
}
```

The razor file then has:

```
@using ( Html.BeginForm( ) )
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.SearchOptions.Page )

    // ValidationSummary calculating 'Start 4 End'??
    @Html.ValidationSummary( false )

    // ... form fields .... 

    <span class="right">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button saveOrSubmit" />
    </span>
    @Html.ActionLink( "Cancel", "Index", Model.SearchOptions )
}
```

Samples:

Using /Create?page=Hello
[image]

Using /Create?Page=Start%20%7B%7Bsum%3d(2*2.0)%7D%7D%20End
[image]

Comment: Please provide more information about how you're getting this to happen. Specifically, it would help to see the Razor code for displaying the validation message and the definition of the `page` property. Out of curiosity, I tried to recreate this and could not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just found out it is an Angular page and the summary sits in the scope that it is evaluated by Angular...